# Update kernel on ARM device

Tags: kernel, boot-loader, arm

How can I update the kernel of my ARM device? The device I have been using is `A20-Olinuxino` `LIME` board, with`Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)` image booted from `NAND`.

The `uname -a` command displays `3.4.102`. I updated `Wheezy` to `Jessie` but after reboot the `uname -a` command still displays the old version of kernel (3.4.102). In `lib/modules` directory there are modules of the new version (3.16.0-4-armp) and in boot directory there are these files:

```
config-3.16.0-4-armmp script.bin uImage initrd.img-3.16.0-4-armmp System.map-3.16.0-4-armmp vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-armmp
```

Why does `uname -a` not display the new version of Kernel? P.S. `cat /etc/debian_version` displays the new Debian version 8.4.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that the kernel is loaded from flash BEFORE the filesystem gets mounted. You need to

- connect to the serial port (with USB-SERIAL-CABLE-F)
- reboot the board and watch the serial output.
- interrupt the bootloader
- load a different kernel image into ram (via tftp or similar)
- transfer the kernel image to flash (do not overwrite the old kernel)
- configure the bootloader to load the new image.

Actual commands depend on the used bootloader.
Feel free to ping this thread if in doubt...

Comment: You said me that kernel isn't loaded from boot directory, is it true? So, which of this file : config-3.16.0-4-armmp initrd.img-3.16.0-4-armmp System.map-3.16.0-4-armmp vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-armmp can I load into ram as kernel image? How can I transfer the kernel image to flash nand?